# $L^2$ and $L^1$ space problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$, is $L^2\subset L^1$ always true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. $L^2(\mathbb R^+) \not\subset L^1(\mathbb R^+)$. You need a finite measure space. An example for my claim is
$$f(x) = \frac1{x+1}$$
$f\in L^2(\mathbb R^+) \setminus L^1(\mathbb R^+)$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand it right or not. Do you mean $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^{+}$, $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{+})$, and $\mu$ is lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Ben Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I may have a stupid question, but Riemann integral is equal to Lebesgue integral when it is bounded function on bounded domain.

Comment: @Ben This is better suited for a new question if you can't find the answer with a little searching. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Sorry about that. This is a very excellent answer.